# Vim replace only if a word

Tags: vim

I am almost always using the `%s/replace_me/replace_with/g` command. 
The problem is very simple to explain - if we have' lets say `"aa aabc aa bcaa"` and we want to replace `aa` with, let's say `bb` then the words `'aabc'` and `'bcaa'` will also be affected which I don't want to happen. In what way should I alter the search and replace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surround the search string with `<` and `>`. Note that you'll need to escape them

```
%s/\<aa\>/bb/g
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I will mark it as the answer when the limit expires.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
%s/replace_me/replace_with/gc
```

`c` - confirm. It will ask you `y/n` for every replacement instead of replacing all at once.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but thanks for pointing out `/c`, I never knew about it!